# HTMLElement.classList.add('myClass') not working. Angular/Typescript

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

In my ts file i create an element and set its class to 'participant-name' as follows:

```
const text = document.createElement('div');
text.classList.add('participant-name');
```

I have my design on css file:

```
.participant-name {
  some attributes...
}
```

But when i run it, it cannot fetch this css files. Also, anything not override them.

I use Angular 14.1.0.

Screenshots of Browser's developer tools:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/view-encapsulation

Comment: You should set this class using template binding. Don't use querySelector etc in Angular, it has its own ways of dealing with DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Eugene 's comment. Encapsulation was my problem. i added this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'dummy',
  templateUrl: './dummy.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dummy.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

And my problem is solved. Thanks again!